# Number of ways to pick 4 people in a circle where no 2 of them are next to each other

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 12 people standing in a circle. Find the number of ways to choose 4 of them such that the no 2 of them consecutive.(Number of ways to pick 4 people where no 2 of them are next to each other! )

### I also wrote a program that calculate all possible status and they are 105 status.

```
 8    12     3     5
```

---

```
 9     3     7    11
```

---

```
 2     4     8    10
```

---

```
 7    11     3     1
```

---

```
12     2     5     7
```

---

```
 8     2     4    11
```

---

```
 7     3     9     5
```

---

```
12     5     2     9
```

---

```
12     4     2     9
```

---

```
 3     6    11     1
```

---

```
 4     8    11     1
```

---

```
 4     1    11     6
```

---

```
 7     5     2    10
```

---

```
 4    12     7     9
```

---

```
10     4     2     7
```

---

```
 2     8     5    11
```

---

```
 9    11     2     6
```

---

```
 9     4    11     2
```

---

```
 1     9     5    11
```

---

```
 7     3     9    12
```

---

```
 2     5    10     8
```

---

```
 5     9    12     3
```

---

```
 2    12     8    10
```

---

```
 5     3     1     8
```

---

```
 2     4    10     6
```

---

```
11     8     6     3
```

---

```
 1     8     6     3
```

---

```
11     7     3     5
```

---

```
 2     9     7    11
```

---

```
10     5     7     3
```

---

```
 3     8    12     6
```

---

```
11     8     6     1
```

---

```
 5     2     7    11
```

---

```
11     6     9     1
```

---

```
 1     7     9     5
```

---

```
 9     3    12     6
```

---

```
11     6     3     9
```

---

```
 2     6     8    12
```

---

```
12     5    10     7
```

---

```
 6     4    12     8
```

---

```
 4     9     6     1
```

---

```
12     8     4    10
```

---

```
 1     3    10     6
```

---

```
 1     4     9    11
```

---

```
 6     8     4     2
```

---

```
 1    11     5     3
```

---

```
 1     7    10     3
```

---

```
 6    12     3    10
```

---

```
 5     1     7    10
```

---

```
 6     4    10     1
```

---

```
12    10     4     6
```

---

```
 6    11     4     8
```

---

```
 4     7     2    11
```

---

```
 7     1     9     3
```

---

```
 9     1     3     5
```

---

```
10     7     4    12
```

---

```
 1    10     5     3
```

---

```
 4     7     9     2
```

---

```
12     5     3     7
```

---

```
12     7    10     3
```

---

```
 9     2     7     5
```

---

```
 3    10     8     6
```

---

```
11     3     9     5
```

---

```
12     2     8     4
```

---

```
 7    12     9     5
```

---

```
 2    11     6     4
```

---

```
 7     4    10     1
```

---

```
 1     3     8    10
```

---

```
 5    11     8     1
```

---

```
 2     5    10    12
```

---

```
10     8     5    12
```

---

```
 2    12     4     7
```

---

```
 1     7    11     4
```

---

```
 9    12     4     6
```

---

```
 4     1    10     8
```

---

```
 4     9     6    11
```

---

```
 3     5     8    11
```

---

```
 4     8     1     6
```

---

```
 3     7     1     5
```

---

```
 9     7     4     1
```

---

```
 6     2     9    12
```

---

```
 6     1     9     3
```

---

```
 6     2     4    12
```

---

```
 4     9    11     7
```

---

```
 2     6    10    12
```

---

```
 9     5     2    11
```

---

```
 2     9     7    12
```

---

```
10     1     8     5
```

---

```
 7    10    12     2
```

---

```
11     3     1     8
```

---

```
 5     7     1    11
```

---

```
10     4     8     6
```

---

```
 6    10     8     2
```

---

```
 6     9     2     4
```

---

```
 8    12    10     3
```

---

```
11     1     7     9
```

---

```
10     6    12     8
```

---

```
 3    12     5    10
```

---

```
 8    11     2     6
```

---

```
 1     8    10     6
```

---

```
 7    11     9     5
```

---

```
 2     4    12    10
```

---

```
10     3     5     8
```

---

```
11     1     3     9
```

---

```
 5     8    12     2
```

---

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  For instance, what would you do if the people were standing in a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as a straight line and you want to pick 4 people. We denote these 4 people by "1". Hence, if I have 010100010001, means I have picked person 2, person 4, person 8, person 12. I also need to remember that I cannot pick person 1 and person 20 (because they are beside each other)

Since we cannot pick 2 consecutive people, I denote it in this way:
Now Case 1 (Last person is chosen, first person not chosen)

_ 010 _ 10 _ 10 _ 1.

(I have 4 chosen people, and 4 other people to block my chosen people, so that I will not end up picking 2 consecutive people, in addition, I can ensure that my first person is not chosen). Now I distribute the remaining 4 people (4 balls) into 4 spaces (4 boxes). I will have that ${4+4-1 \choose 4} = {7 \choose 4}$

Case 2: (First person is chosen)

10 _ 10 _ 10 _ 10 _ (I have 4 chosen people, and I use another 4 people to block my chosen people, so that I will not end up picking 2 consecutive person. In addition, I placed one more guy at the back to ensure that the last guy is not chosen) Again, I am now distributing the remaining 4 people (4 balls) into 4 spaces (4 boxes). I will have that ${4+4-1 \choose 4} = {7 \choose 4}$

Case 3: Neither the first nor last person is chosen
_ 010 _ 10 _ 10 _ 10 _. Then I am just distributing 3 balls into 5 boxes and hence I will have that ${3+5-1 \choose 3} = {7 \choose 3}$

Hence, my answer is just ${7 \choose 3}+2{7 \choose 4}=105$, as per your computation

Comment: Just to clarify, in my first case, notice if I just let it be _ 10 _ 10 _ 10 _ 1, then there might be a chance I can still pick the first person (and the last person) because I might just distribute all my balls into the 2nd box (which is a possibility). Hence, I must ensure that my first person is not picked by putting another person in front of him :)

Comment: hello and thank you for answering me . i wrote a program that calculates all possible positions for selected people . and there are 105 different states shown bellow. is it right?

Comment: Ahh! I'm sorry!! I thought there were 20 people! Do let me edit the answer and get back to you if it's 105! So sorry about it!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! otherwise I wouldn't have known I misread the number of people at the table!